# Metodo compare de Integer nunca devuelve mas de 1 en Java 8

Tags: java

Según la documentación el método devuelve un int mayor que 0 si es mayor o menor que 0 si es menor, pero mirando el método se ve que siempre devuelve -1, 0, 1.

> Returns:the value 0 if x == y;a value less than 0 if x < y; anda value
>   greater than 0 if x > y

Y luego el código:

```
 /**
     * Compares two {@code int} values numerically.
     * The value returned is identical to what would be returned by:
     * <pre>
     *    Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(y))
     * </pre>
     *
     * @param  x the first {@code int} to compare
     * @param  y the second {@code int} to compare
     * @return the value {@code 0} if {@code x == y};
     *         a value less than {@code 0} if {@code x < y}; and
     *         a value greater than {@code 0} if {@code x > y}
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public static int compare(int x, int y) {
        return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
    }
```

Entonces mi duda es, ¿cuando implementas un comparable hay que comprobar que te llega -1,0,1 o *Integers* mayores, iguales o menores a 0?.

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema. ¿Es que -1 no es menor que cero? ¿Cual es el problema con que sea -1 o -245? Tu comparación debería ser: menor que 0, igual a 0 o mayor que 0. Especifica un poco mejor qué problema tienes para tratar de entenderte.

Comment: No es que sea un problema, es una duda de porque la documentación no te indica que devuelve esos valores, en cambio para "compareTo" o "compare" de Comparator si te especifica que tiene que devolver esos valores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está claramente explicado, en **los comentarios** del [código fuente de JDK 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l1219), que es el caso que expones :

```
/**
 * Compares two {@code int} values numerically.
 * The value returned is identical to what would be returned by:
 * <pre>
 *    Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(y))
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param  x the first {@code int} to compare
 * @param  y the second {@code int} to compare
 * @return the value {@code 0} if {@code x == y};
 *         a value less than {@code 0} if {@code x < y}; and
 *         a value greater than {@code 0} if {@code x > y}
 * @since 1.7
 */
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Quizá no sea muy claro en la [documentación de la clase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-), pero se entiende:

> **Returns:**
>
> the value `0` if `x == y`; a value less than `0` if `x < y`; and a
>   value greater than `0` if `x > y`

Traducido y diseccionado, para que se vea claro, significa:

> **Retorna:**
>
> - `0`, si `x == y`
> - un valor menor que `0` (**entiéndase `-1`** ) si `x < y`
> - un valor mayor que `0` (**entiéndase `1`**) `x > y`

Es decir, `compare()` devuelve solamente tres valores posibles:

- `0`  si `x == y`
- `-1` si `x < y`
- `1`  si `x > y`

---

### Prueba

Usando el método del código fuente de JDK 8 indicado más arriba:

```
System.out.format("x == y [ %d ]%n",compare(20,20));/* [  0 ] -> @return the value {@code 0} if {@code x == y} */
System.out.format("x < y  [%d ]%n",compare(10,20));/*  [ -1 ] -> @return a value less than {@code 0} if {@code x < y} */
System.out.format("x > y  [ %d ]%n",compare(40,30));/* [  1 ] -> @return a value greater than {@code 0} if {@code x > y} */
```

**Salida:**

```
x == y [ 0 ]
x < y  [-1 ]
x > y  [ 1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Por añadir a los comentarios y respuestas que hay hasta ahora:

El método `compareTo` de la clase `Integer` no es muy útil en sí mismo si lo llamas de esta manera:

```
Integer a = 100;
Integer b = 200;
Integer comparacion = a.compareTo(b);
if (comparacion > 0) {
   // Código si a > b
} else if (comparacion < 0) {
   // Código si a < b
} else {
   // Código si a == b
}
```

Ya que se podría haber hecho directamente así:

```
if (a > b) {
   // Código si a > b
} else if (a < b) {
   // Código si a < b
} else {
   // Código si a == b
}
```

El método `compareTo` tiene sentido si lo usas para comparar estructuras más complejas como un String u otro tipo de objetos.

Dicho eso, ¿para qué querríamos saber si un objeto es "mayor" o "menor" que otros?. El caso más utilizado es para definir un orden cuando se tiene una colección de dichos objetos. De esta manera podríamos ordenar los elementos de mayor a menor o viceversa.

En estos casos es cuando definimos nuestra función de comparación, ya que `Integer` y String proveen su propia implementación de compareTo, pero para las clases que creeemos nosotros tenemos que definirla.

Imagina que tenemos una clase Coche, con atributos marca y modelo.

```
public class Coche implements Comparable<Coche> {

  private String marca;
  private String modelo;

  public Coche(String marca, String modelo) {
    this.marca = marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
  }

  public String getMarca() {
    return this.marca;
  }

  public String getModelo() {
    return this.modelo;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return marca + " " + modelo;
  }

  public int compareTo(Coche otro) {
    int resultado = marca.compareTo(otro.getMarca());
    if (resultado == 0) {
      resultado = modelo.compareTo(otro.getModelo());
    }
    return resultado;
  }

}
```

En esta clase, hemos implementado la interfaz `Comparable<Coche>` para poder comparar dos coches entre sí. Para esta implementación, lo que se hace es comparar primero la marca (usando el método `compareTo` de la clase `String`). En el caso de que sean iguales, es decir, se recibe un 0, se compara una vez más; pero esta vez se compara el modelo del coche.

Una vez hecho esto, ya podemos saber si un coche es "mayor" o "menor" que otro en el sentido de si se tiene que ordenar "antes" o "después" en una colección. De esta manera "Seat León" es mayor que "Seat Panda" y éste a su vez mayor que "Toyota Yaris"

Podemos implementar la ordenación de esta manera:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Coche> coches = new ArrayList<Coche>();
  coches.add(new Coche("Toyota", "Yaris"));
  coches.add(new Coche("Seat", "Panda"));
  coches.add(new Coche("Seat", "León"));
  Collections.sort(coches);
  System.out.print(coches);
}
```

La salida es:

> [Seat León, Seat Panda, Toyota Yaris]

Lo que quiero que veas con este ejemplo, es que desde el programa principal **no hemos llamado a nuestra función `compareTo` de forma explícita**. Sino que hemos llamado a `Collections.sort`, que **internamente ha llamado a nuestro método `compareTo`**, para determinar qué coche es mayor o menor que otro y así poder ordenar la lista.

Por otra parte, desde nuestro método `compareTo` no hay problema en llamar a otros métodos `compareTo` de otra clases, tal y como hemos hecho para comparar las cadenas de caracteres que son nuestra marca y nuestro modelo de coche.